# Ignore regex capturing group when using javascript split

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split up a string into an array, and I'm looking to get back an array with the following format: `['a','b', 'c']`

```
const code = "/*_ ex1.js */a/*_ ex2.js */b/*_ ex3.js */c"
code.split(/\/\*_.+?\*\//)
```

=> (This is what I want)

```
['a','b', 'c']
```

But when I try to ensure that the regex works with new lines

```
code.split(/\/\*_(.|\s)+?\*\//)
```

=>(Not what I want)

```
[' ', 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c']
```

I have no idea where these extra spaces are coming from. It obviously has something to do with the bracketed capturing group, but I don't understand how to get around that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` includes the contents of any capturing group in the output. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

In your case, the `(.|\s)` is a capturing group. Therefore, spaces are getting included in your output. The easiest way around this is to make it a non-capturing group with `?:`:

```
code.split(/\/\*_(?:.|\s)+?\*\//)
                  ^^
```

This still leaves you with an initial empty string in the resulting array. (Your initial, non-multi-line version also behaves that way.) There is no way around that, since your splitter is coming right at the beginning of the string, and so the token to the left is an empty string. If you want to get rid of that, you could filter it out:

```
.filter(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/[a-z](?=\/|\n|$)/g` to match character class `a` through `z` followed by `/` character or newline character or end of input

```js
const code = "/*_ ex1.js */a/*_ ex2.js */b/*_ ex3.js */c\n"
             + "/*_ ex4.js */d/*_ ex5.js */e/*_ ex6.js */f";
var res = code.match(/[a-z](?=\/|\n|$)/g);
console.log(res);
```